# How would I convert this matrix to a system of equations?

Tags: matrices, determinant, gaussian-elimination

Given a matrix
$$A =\begin{pmatrix}1& 1& 1\\−2& 1& 3\\3& 2& 1\end{pmatrix}$$

use Gaussian elimination to compute the determinant $\det(A)$ of $A$ and to solve
the system of linear equations $AX = b$, where $X = (X_1,X_2,X_3)^T$ is the vector
of unknowns and $b = (1, 0, 1)^T$ . The solution should be represented by simple
fractions. Show your working.

I immediately assume to convert the matrix to the form:

$$x   + y  +  z = \\
-2x + y  +  z = \\
3x  + 2y +  z =$$

My question is what are each of these equal to? I assumed it was 1 , 0, 1 respectively as left to right is top to bottom, but I am not so sure. Thank you for  any help.

Comment: I could possibly help! Try to construct a $2$x$2$ matrix. Remember gaussian elimination is just adding and subtracting equations.

Comment: I think you are right:3x1 matrix with elements 1,0,1 top to bottom.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question easier to read.

Comment: I suppose they ask to perform row reduction until you obtain a triangular matrix. The determinant is then the product of the diagonal elements.

Comment: I managed to figure it out, it was indeed as I believed. det(A) is -1.
Also, X = (3, -6, 4)^T